# check current url in sub menu items

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I want to add a custom active class to side menu that has the current route. I know that I can get current url by `url()->current()` and compare it to `route('something')`, but my challenge is when I want to get the active class both on a parent and child menu item when a child item is selected.

My code for a menu item without any children is:

```
<li class=" @if(url()->current()==route('home')) custom_active_menu @endif ">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use if with multiple or statements for the parent. i use `Request` class generally, so that i can use a pattern with just an asterisk instead of multiple or statement. however you can use use anything as you wish. an exmaple using `Request` class

```
<li class="{{ \Request::is('menu/*') || \Request::is('menu') ? 'active' : ''  }}">
    <a href="#">
        <i class="metismenu-icon pe-7s-bandaid"></i>
        Menu
        <i class="metismenu-state-icon pe-7s-angle-down caret-left"></i>
    </a>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="{{ route('menu.index') }}" class="{{ \Request::is('menu') ? 'active' : ''  }}">
                <i class="metismenu-icon"></i>
                Menu Index
            </a>
        </li>
                        
        <li>
            <a href="{{ route('menu.create') }}" class="{{ \Request::is('menu/create') ? 'active' : ''  }}">
                <i class="metismenu-icon"></i>
                Menu Create
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

here i am checking for a pattern in request url using `\Request::is('menu/*')`, which means this `li` will always be active if the request url matches any pattern starting by `menu/` like `menu/create` or `menu/1/edit`. with an or statement i am checking for exact request url `menu`.

with child, it' just a simple if statement. if the current url matches with the menu url add the class active.

with your example, i would do something like for parent

```
<li class=" @if (url()->current() == route('home') || url()->current() == route('another_route')) custom_active_menu @endif ">
```

and for child just a single if

```
<li class=" @if (url()->current() == route('home')) custom_active_menu @endif ">
```